# Adding checkbox to collapsible list header in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm stuck with a problem in jQuery Mobile website. I'm working on a jQuery mobile website with collapsible list (http://dev.sreejesh.in/jqmobile/inbox.html).

My client needs to have a checkbox inside the header, so that user can check the list without opening it. I tried to put it inside but it doesn't work well. The checkbox appears, but it is not clickable. I have searched in google a lot but couldn't find a solution. Hope you guys could help me. please.....

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Make sure you give your checkboxes a unique ID if you have more than one. Don't forget the checkboxes labels too.

```
<div id="collapsibleSetWrapper" data-role="collapsible-set">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
        <h3>
           <span>some title</span>
           <input class="mycheckbox" type="checkbox" id="uniqueID"/>
           <label for="uniqueID">&nbsp;</label>
        </h3>
        <div id="mycontent">
              <p>this is the content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>    
$('#collapsibleSetWrapper .mycheckbox').checkboxradio({
    create: function(event,ui){
        var checkbox = $(event.target);
        var clickTarget = $(event.target).parent();
        $(clickTarget).click(function(e){
            if($(checkbox).is(':checked')){
                $(checkbox).attr("checked",false).checkboxradio("refresh");
                // select all the nested checkboxes here
            }
            else{
                $(checkbox).attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
                // unselect all the nested checkboxes here
            }
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Courtesy wouldn't go amiss. Thanks Ed, may not have worked for him but certainly worked for me.

Comment: @Edd For me, the code almost works perfectly, my problem is that an unchecked checkbox can only be checked and rechecked once. Checking it again (= third click) is not possible. Can you understand me?

Comment: @Max I'm not sure, but try this: instead of  if($(checkbox).is(':checked')) use if($(checkbox).prop('checked')==true). Also, replace all the $(checkbox).attr('checked',...) with $(checkbox).prop('checked',...) . Let me now. If it works I'll edit my answer.